# Positioning API support on desktop platforms

Tags: geolocation, webkit, qt5

I've tried to build a webkit app using HTML5 geoposition APIs to get the current coordinates. I've also turned on the geolocation feature but it fails to start with error

> Failed to start Geolocation service

Then I've tried to use `QGetPositionInfoSource`, but it can't find any available source to use. I wonder, is Positioning API supported on desktop applications?

Comment: Updated with the new information: please take in account the beta snapshot of Qt 5.6 since it has the functionality you are searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a big **no-no**.

Directly from the documentation:

> The Qt Positioning API provides positioning information via QML and C++ interfaces. Currently the API is supported on **Android**, **BlackBerry 10**, **iOS** and **Linux** (using **GeoClue**).

The same applies for Qt 5.4 as can be seen in the corresponding snapshot documentation page here.

### UPDATE

Support for the whole **BlackBerry** platform has been dropped. On the other hand, **support for Positioning API on desktop platforms will be available with the next release of the framework, Qt 5.6**. The current [documentation](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qtpositioning-index.html) snapshot is pretty clear about that:

> The Qt Positioning API provides positioning information via QML and C++ interfaces.
>
> Currently the API is supported on **Android**, **iOS**, **OS X**, **Linux** (using **GeoClue** version 0.12.99), **Windows** (with **GPS receivers** exposed as a serial port providing NMEA sentences), and **WinRT** (using **Windows.Devices.Geolocation**).

Thus, download a development snapshot and try out this new desktop feature.